# MySQLi to PDO issue with prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Trying to move to PDO and having a helluva time. Here's my code, which isn't working quite right:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pp_production;charset=utf8', 'mr', 'jones');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$report_date = "DATE(time_track.punch_in) = CURRENT_DATE ORDER BY time_track.punch_in DESC";

$query_clock_history = $db->prepare("SELECT time_track.id, time_track.job_id, first_name, activity, time_track.comments, time_track.punch_in, time_track.punch_out, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, time_track.punch_in, time_track.punch_out) AS time_spent, customers.customer_name, typesetting.description, typesetting.job_ticket FROM typesetting 
JOIN time_track ON typesetting.id = time_track.job_id 
JOIN employees ON employees.id = time_track.employee_id 
JOIN activities ON activities.id = time_track.activity_id 
JOIN customers ON customers.id = typesetting.customers_id 
WHERE :report_date");
$query_clock_history->bindValue(':report_date', $report_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_clock_history->execute();
```

So, that returns no results. If I replace :report_date with the actual contents of the $report_date variable, it works. I've been banging my head against this for a while now and just can't get it to work. Any help greatly appreciated. This is running on MAMP, if that makes a difference.

Tried some things that didn't work

```
$report_date = "CURRENT_DATE";
...
WHERE DATE(time_track.punch_in) = :report_date ORDER BY time_track.punch_in DESC");
```

Still nothing. It seems like a simple example but I don't know why it won't work.

Comment: did you get any error out there ?

Comment: [PDO query fails but I can't see any errors. How to get an error message from PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo#15990858)

Comment: is your $report_date giving right value on echo.....???

Comment: any reason you are binding WHERE part?

Comment: I have a switch statement to change out the WHERE part of the query depending on what has been submitted by the user.

Comment: Well, if there are no variables involved just concatenate this variable part to your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You can't bind an arbitrary query part but scalar value only (i.e. string and number), neither in PDO or mysqli

Nevertheless, you don't need no binding for this query at all

```
$sql = "SELECT time_track.id, time_track.job_id, first_name, activity, time_track.comments, time_track.punch_in, time_track.punch_out, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, time_track.punch_in, time_track.punch_out) AS time_spent, customers.customer_name, typesetting.description, typesetting.job_ticket FROM typesetting 
JOIN time_track ON typesetting.id = time_track.job_id 
JOIN employees ON employees.id = time_track.employee_id 
JOIN activities ON activities.id = time_track.activity_id 
JOIN customers ON customers.id = typesetting.customers_id 
WHERE DATE(time_track.punch_in) = CURRENT_DATE ORDER BY time_track.punch_in DESC"

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

that's all

Comment: I'll restructure my query then. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Since there's no binding, there's also no need for prepare and execute; just query.

Answer (score 0):

Your where must have a condition, i.e

```
WHERE date = :report_date
```

from php website

```
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$sth->bindParam(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':colour', $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$sth->execute();
```

Therefore, your :report_date param needs to have a condition against a colomn in from your table in your query statement

Comment: I just tried doing what you suggested but that doesn't seem to work either. Maybe I'm misunderstanding:  

    $report_date = "CURRENT_DATE ORDER BY time_track.punch_in DESC";  
    ...  
    WHERE DATE(time_track.punch_in) = :report_date");

Comment: What is the type of time_track.punch_in, does it match :report_date, may be the formats/type are different